# How to find method of moments estimator when 1 parameter is known and 1 is unknown?

Tags: self-study, method-of-moments

Let X1,…,Xn be a random sample from a distribution with cumulative distribution function
$$
F(x)=
\begin {cases} 0 & \text{x < 0;}\\(x/β)^α & \text{0 ≤ x ≤ β;}\\
1 & \text{x > β}
\end{cases}$$

Assume $\alpha$ is known and $\beta$ is unknown. Find the method of moments estimator of $\beta_{MOM}$ of $\beta$ and its mean square error, *MSE*($\beta_{MOM}$).

This question has me stumped.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

A known parameter is just a constant, so you have a MoM problem with one parameter.

There's no difficulty here. The usual method of moments can be used in simple fashion. It's a few lines of algebra (unless you recognize the distribution and know its mean already, in which case it's two lines at most)

1. What's the basic definition/methodology of method of moments that you have? (be sure to also edit any substantive responses to this one into your question, since it tells us something about what you know about MoM)
2. What's the mean of the distribution?